# How do I select destination directory for tar command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, tar

I'm wanting to tar a folder called "mysite" to the destination directory: /var/backups/

I'm trying to issue the following command:

```
tar -C /var/www/mysite/ -zcf mysite_$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz /var/backups/
```

However, it's ending up with:

> tar: C: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
>
> tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

I've checked and confirmed that /var/backups/ is a valid directory.

Basically what I want to do is, to tar the mysite folder "/var/backup/mysite" into a file called mysite_yymmdd.tar.gz which sould be available in /var/backups/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you want but you can just put the destination in the path

```
tar -zcf /var/backups/mysite_$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz /var/www/mysite/
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may have forgotten the `-` in `-C` when you typed it into the command line. The compiler is saying that `C` is not a directory; it would only think it's a directory if the `-` was left off.

Don't worry, even the best of us make command line typos... :-)

Comment: Thanks. I've put the - before the C. Here's the command I've been trying: tar -C /var/www/mysite/ -zcf mysite_$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz /var/backups/

Comment: If I change the destination directory to current by using 
tar -C /var/www/mysite/ -zcf mysite_$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz ./
it works fine, but I need it to create the tars in a particular directory.

Comment: You could just make the file and then move it to the desired folder, then. Also, if you use the command with the destination directory, what error does it give? It would not give "C: No such file or directory" if you use `-C`.